# How to create a single raster based on the values of three rasters (Conditional)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.6, conditional

I have three rasters of soil granulometric fractions (clay, sand and silt), all in %. I want to make a single raster of the soil texture classes. For that, I need to make some conditionals (i. e.: when sand > 90 and clay < 10, so the class in the new raster must have the value 1).

Any suggestion? I'm using Arcgis 10.6.

Comment: Do they have the same extent and resolution?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [raster calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) of arcgis ?

Comment: @BERA yes. All the rasters hava the same resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Try converting your rasters to numpy arrays, build a classifying function and convert resulting Array back to raster. (This way you dont need Spatial Analyst extension)

Example with two random rasters with values from 0-1. Modify the function etc:

```py
import numpy as np
import arcpy

raster1 = "randraster_1" #Change
raster2 = "randraster_2" #Change
output_raster = r'C:\Default.gdb\resultraster123' #Change

arr1 = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster1)
arr2 = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster2)

def whatsoil(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return 1
    elif a<b:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
vwhatsoil = np.vectorize(whatsoil)

arr3 = vwhatsoil(arr1, arr2)

desc = arcpy.Describe(raster1+r'/Band_1')
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = desc.spatialReference

resultraster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(in_array=arr3, lower_left_corner=desc.extent.lowerLeft, x_cell_size=desc.meanCellHeight, y_cell_size=desc.meanCellWidth)
resultraster.save(output_raster)
```

[image]

Comment: if you're using numpy, you'll likely get much better performance with `numpy.where` over your `whatsoil` function

Comment: Ok! I did not know how to do it with 3 input arrays and many if elses so i used a function instead

Comment: You should be able to `numpy.where(a > b, 1, numpy.where(a < b, 2, 3))`. `numpy.select` works in this case too.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the raster calculator, but it quickly creates long statement

Map algebra > raster calculator, for example :

> Con(("sand" > 90) and ("clay" <10 ), 1, Con(("silt">50) and
>   ("clay"<30),2,3)

The syntax is Con (condition, value if true, value if false)